# Using Automapper with a collection of abstract objects

Tags: c#, automapper

Please take a look at this rather contrived example of what I'm trying to do.

First, the database models:

```
public class Report
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Worker> Workers { get; set; } 
}

public abstract class Worker
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Fireman : Worker
{
    public string Station { get; set; }
}

public class Cleaner : Worker
{
    public string FavoriteSolvent { get; set; }
}
```

Now the view models:

```
public class AddReportViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AddFiremanViewModel> Firemen { get; set; }
    public List<AddCleanerViewModel> Cleaners { get; set; }
}

public class AddFiremanViewModel
{
    public string Station { get; set; }
}

public class AddCleanerViewModel
{
    public string FavoriteSolvent { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the Automapper profile:

```
public class ReportProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<AddReportViewModel, Report>();
        CreateMap<AddFiremanViewModel, Fireman>();
        CreateMap<AddCleanerViewModel, Cleaner>();
    }
}
```

I want the `Firemen` and `Cleaners` to both populate the `Workers` collection, which is an `ICollection<Worker>`.  I hope this makes sense.  How can I do this?

Comment: You mean you want to combine `Firemen` and `Cleaners` into one collection?  How?  Just `Union` them?

Comment: Yes, a union.  If there are two firemen and one cleaner, the result should contain three workers.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [custom value resolvers](https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view model doesn't contain any `Id` field so I set those up as `Ignore` in the mapping.  Then, I just used LINQ's `Union` clause to combine the two source lists into a single collection (after converting each one using Automapper).  Here's the mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AddReportViewModel, Report>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.Workers, o => o.MapFrom(
        s => Mapper.Map<ICollection<AddFiremanViewModel>, ICollection<Fireman>>(s.Firemen)
            .Union<Worker>(Mapper.Map<ICollection<AddCleanerViewModel>, ICollection<Cleaner>>(s.Cleaners))))
    ;
Mapper.CreateMap<AddFiremanViewModel, Fireman>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.Ignore())
    ;
Mapper.CreateMap<AddCleanerViewModel, Cleaner>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.Ignore())
    ;
```

And here's an example of using it:

```
var vm = new AddReportViewModel
{
    Name = "Sample",
    Cleaners = new List<AddCleanerViewModel>
    {
        new AddCleanerViewModel {FavoriteSolvent = "Alcohol"}
    },
    Firemen = new List<AddFiremanViewModel>
    {
        new AddFiremanViewModel {Station = "51"},
        new AddFiremanViewModel {Station = "49"}
    }
};

var db = Mapper.Map<AddReportViewModel, Report>(vm);
```